# On the convergence of an infinite product

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Let $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \in (0,1].
$$
Is it possible to show that for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+m} a_k =1?
$$
Since the infinte product is non-zero, then clearly $a_k >0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. For every fixed $m \in \mathbb{N}$ we can further rewrite
$$
\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+m} a_k = \prod_{k=1}^{m} a_{n+k}.
$$
What further observations can be made?

Comment: *Hint.* Write $P_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ and note that $$\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+m}a_k=\frac{P_{n+m}}{P_{n}}. $$

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to prove that
$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{log(a_k)} = log(\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}{a_k})$

so because the series is convergent is also a cauchy series and therefore for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ we get

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}{\sum_{k=n}^{n+m}{\log(a_k)}} = 0$$

Applying the exponential function both sides and interchanging the limit with the exponenctial by the continuity you get the thesis